# Creating a Table in SQL

Tags: sql

I am not sure why this syntax does not work. I want to create a new table that merges two existing tables.

```
CREATE TABLE blah(
SELECT T1.Q1, T1.Q2, T1.Q3, T1.ID, T1.QOL, T2.ID, T2.L1, T2.L2
FROM T1, T2
WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID)
```

Comment: what kind of database are you using mysql oracle postgres or something else.
in Oracle this would be something like this: `create table test_table as select * from dual;`
and the error message you are receiving would be useful as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah whole query is correct just AS is missing.

```
CREATE TABLE blah AS (
SELECT T1.Q1, T1.Q2, T1.Q3, T1.ID, T1.QOL, T2.ID, T2.L1, T2.L2
FROM T1, T2
WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

look like you are missing as here,try

```
CREATE TABLE blah as (
SELECT T1.BUSINESSNAME, T1.STREETADDRESS, T1.CITYNAME, T1.ID, T1.QOL, T2.ID, T2.L1, T2.L2
FROM T1, T2
WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID)
```

Comment: Is that specific to Netzilla?

Comment: @lord12 no, it is generally sql syntax.

Comment: When I went online and searched, I just saw the parentheses and no "as". I guess the website was wrong.

Comment: @lord12  where do you find your website? i even could not find Netzilla? what is Netzilla anyway?

Comment: @lord12 ok i see, but i do not know if it is the case.i test it in the oracle.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.Q1, T1.Q2, T1.Q3, T1.ID, T1.QOL, T2.ID, T2.L1, T2.L2
INTO blah
FROM T1, T2
WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of column ID is specified two times: in T1.ID and in T2.ID.
At least in postgres this is not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can create table using below code

```
SELECT *
INTO #MyNewTable
FROM SourceTale
```

Comment: Does this work in MYSQL by any chance because I get an undeclared variable error.